# Merge 3 lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an issue merging some lists together, I thought this would be a simple LINQ join but I think a little more complex and I'm going in circles. I have 3 tables below:

**Table 1: Master list of products**

| Product |
| --- |
| PROD1 |
| PROD2 |
| PROD3 |
| PROD4 |

**Table 2: Product and corresponding Leaflet**

| Product | Leaflet |
| --- | --- |
| PROD1 | Docu23 |
| PROD2 | Docu18 |
| PROD3 | Docu322 |
| PROD4 | Docu121 |

**Table 3: Product and corresponding Labels**

| Product | Label |
| --- | --- |
| PROD1 | Lbl29 |
| PROD2 | Lbl2 |
| PROD3 | Lbl222 |
| PROD5 | Lbl01 |

Final result should be:-

| Product | Leaflet | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PROD1 | Docu23 | Lbl29 |
| PROD2 | Docu18 | Lbl2 |
| PROD3 | Docu322 | Lbl222 |
| PROD4 | Docu121 |  |
| PROD5 |  | Lbl01 |

***Note: Some Products can have no leaflet and some Products can have no label. Also, leaflets and labels can be associated with more than one product.***

Here's the query i tried, it brings everything together but there are many odd duplicates of rows.

```
PMatrix = (from a in AllProducts
           join b in Leaflets on a.Product equals b.Product into b_grp
           from b in b_grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join c in Labels on a.Product equals c.Product into c_grp
           from c in c_grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new ProductMatrixModel
           {
               Product = a.Product,
               Leaflet = b == null ? "" : b.Leaflet, 
               Label = c == null ? "" : c.Label
           }).ToBindableCollection();
```

Sorry for the ugly stretched tables, I cannot see how to set the widths.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what i meant, ill update.

Comment: 'Some Products can have no leaflet and some leaflets can have no label' - but you're joining both tables to product, without an additional clause for leaflets to labels.

Comment: Ah, I see the update. Thanks, now I understand.

Comment: Is this data in a db/do you need the answer to be translatable to an SQL of the form A LEFT JOIN B LEFT JOIN C?

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that your master list of products lacks Prod5 - typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not test the below code, but if you're into LINQ expressions, you could try something like this. I did something similar a while back.

```
AllProducts
.GroupJoin(Leaflets , l => l.Product, r => r.Product, (a, b) => new ProductMatrixModel { Product = a, Leaflet = b.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty })
.GroupJoin(Labels, l => l.Product, r => r.Product, (a, b) => new ProductMatrixModel { Product = a.Product , Leaflet = a.Leaflet, Label = b.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty })
.ToBindableCollection();
```

The above expression uses 'FirstOrDefault', so it will take the first result from possible join matches. If you require all the join matches, then you need to update your modal property to a list and work with the data accordingly.

Example of what I mentioned above would be:

1. Change Modal to something like this

   ```
   public class ProductMatrixModel
   {
      public ProductMatrixModel()
      {
         this.Labels = new List<string>();
         this.Leaflets = new List<string>();
      }

      public string Product { get; set; }
      public List<string> Labels { get; set; }
      public List<string> Leaflets { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Then use the LINQ expression like this:

   ```
   AllProducts
   .GroupJoin(Leaflets , l => l.Product, r => r.Product, (a, b) => new ProductMatrixModel { Product = a, Leaflets = b })
   .GroupJoin(Labels, l => l.Product, r => r.Product, (a, b) => new ProductMatrixModel { Product = a.Product , Leaflets = a.Leaflets, Labels = b })
   .ToBindableCollection();
   ```

The above LINQ query should then give you a IEnumerable, with each ProductMatrixModel object containing the product string, with its associated list of labels and leaflets.

You can the loop each 'ProductMatrixModel' object and do whatever you like with it's associated data. I assume you would like to show it in a comma delimited string.

Here is a example of how to show string list as a comma delimited string.

```
string.Join(",", Leaflets.Select(s => s));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm getting an exception with the second GroupJoin. 
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter, TKey>, Func<TInner, TKey>, Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Oh, I see. It's due to the dynamic objects. I'll update quick

Comment: I updated it, makin it a concrete object on each join instead of dynamic should resolve the issue.

Comment: 'Sequence contains more than on element' exception on the first GroupJoin new ProductMatrixModel { ... }

Comment: Oh I see, you have one or more records that have more than one relation to a leaf or label, just update the following on the joins : FirstOrDefault

Comment: Note, taking the first will ignore the rest of the matching results, so If you want all those matching results you need to store the list of matches

Comment: Looking at your example data, I did not expect more than one label |or| leaflet per product.

Comment: Yes I have to update my question again sorry. A leaflet or label can be on more than one product.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238687/discussion-between-formant-and-b-spangenberg).